# What's the meaning of this paragraph in David Copperfield?

Tags: british-english, literature

> Within the first week of my passion, I bought four sumptuous waistcoats — not for myself; I had no pride in them; for Dora — and took to wearing straw-coloured kid gloves in the streets, and laid the foundations of all the corns I have ever had. If the boots I wore at that period could only be produced and compared with the natural size of my feet, they would show what the state of my heart was, in a most affecting manner.

I understand this paragraph is about what happened to him when David fell in love with Dora.

1. Did he wear straw-coloured kid gloves to attact Dora's attention when he purposely chose to walk on the Norwood Road in hope to meet her (as said in the following paragraph).
2. Completely have no idea about "laid the foundations of all the corns I have ever had".
3. Why his shoes would show the state of his heart? Because he walked a lot on that street in order to meet her?

Answer (score 10):

1 He wore them as you suggest, to attract Dora’s attention

2 He wore boots that were to small for his feet so as to try to look elegant and to attract Dora’s attention. By wearing tight boots he restricted his circulation so much that he predisposed (“laid the foundations of” is an analogy for this, rather like “prepared the ground for“) his feet to develop corns in later life.

3 and therefore, if those boots could somehow now be produced, their painfully small size would indicate the pains and trouble that he had been willing to endure to attract Dora.

Corns were well known to me in my cold youth. Less frequent now, here is a definition:

> [NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/corns-and-calluses/)
>
> Corns and calluses are hard or thick areas of skin that can be painful.

Comment: Beat me to it—maybe improve with a link to the medical definition of [corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_(pathology)), which the OP seems to be missing?

Comment: @AndyBonner good point. But it’s not a race so I look forward to yours too.

Comment: Heh, I discarded since it was pretty much identical.

Comment: The boots weren't necessarily too small ... what is clear is that they hurt his feet.

Comment: @PeterShor agreed not necessarily, although such discomfort (corns rather than blisters, which come from looseness) usually arises from overall or partial smallness (perhaps round the toes, restricting circulation badly)